# Runnable not running on floating action bar on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been trying to get the fab to rotate and change its icon but for some reason the `Runnable` doesn't work at all.

**Here is the code :**

```
private val handler: Handler = Handler()
private var isRotate: Boolean = false
private val rotate: Animation =   RotateAnimation(0.toFloat(),90.toFloat(),0.toFloat(),0.toFloat())

private val r: Runnable = Runnable {
    fun run() {
            if (isRotate) {
                fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, null))
                isRotate = false
            } else {
                fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, null))
                isRotate = true
            }
        }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    ...

    rotate.duration = 1000
    rotate.repeatCount = 0
    rotate.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
    rotate.fillAfter = true

    fab2?.setOnClickListener { view ->
               ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"rotation",0.toFloat(),90.toFloat()).setDuration(800).start()
    view.handler.postDelayed(r,400)
    }
}
```

The Button rotates but icon does not change implying that the `OnClickListener` is working but the `Runnable` isn't.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: If you want to forcing the animation is played when `fab2` is clicked, you should use `fab2!!.onClickListener` or make the `fab2` non-nullable. safe-call operator `?` will ignoring to register any listeners if the left side expression is `null`. which means your `fab2` maybe is `null`.

Comment: As I just edited, the problem isn't fab2 being null, the roate function works fine, but handler doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your `Runnable` in a wrong way. The lambda expression you declare is actually the `run()` function and you declare another `run()` function inside.

Correct way to declare your object should be:

```
private val r: Runnable = object: Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        if (isRotate) {
            fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, null))
            isRotate = false
        } else {
            fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, null))
            isRotate = true
        }
    }
}
```

Or(lambda expression):

```
private val r: Runnable = Runnable {
    if (isRotate) {
        fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, null))
        isRotate = false
    } else {
        fab2.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, null))
        isRotate = true
    }
}
```